# Trying to have the user put a number and it loads a preset into the calculation of the program

Tags: c#

My code is currently skipping the new section I added which asks the material type of the bar. I am unable to figure out where i have messed up the coding in order have it run through every question in order.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{ //silver = 1
  //Aluminum = 0.5f
  //Fiberglass = 0.045f
  //Glass = 0.002f

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()


        {

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    int NumberofUserInputs;
                    string UserInputPrompt = "How many bars to consider? ";
                    string inputstring;
                    Console.Write(UserInputPrompt);
                    inputstring = Console.ReadLine();
                    NumberofUserInputs = int.Parse(inputstring);


                    float[][] barSpecs = new float[NumberofUserInputs][];

                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++)
                    {
                        const float PI = (float)Math.PI;
                        barSpecs[i] = new float[11];
                        int S = 0;
                        int A = 1;
                        int F = 2;
                        int G = 3;
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter Material Type of bar {0}:", i + 1);
                        if (Int32.TryParse(inputstring, out S))
                        { barSpecs[i][1] = (1); }
                        else if (Int32.TryParse(inputstring, out A))
                        { barSpecs[i][1] = (0.5f); }
                        else if (Int32.TryParse(inputstring, out F))
                        { barSpecs[i][1] = (0.045f); }
                        else if (Int32.TryParse(inputstring, out G))
                        { barSpecs[i][1] = (0.002f); }
                        else
                        { Console.WriteLine("restart progam pick number 1-4"); }

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar radius {0}:", i + 1);
                        barSpecs[i][0] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        barSpecs[i][2] = PI * (barSpecs[i][0]) * (barSpecs[i][0]); //area

                        //Console.WriteLine("Enter Bar heat conduction coefficient {0}:", i + 1);// lamda
                        //barSpecs[i][1] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar length {0}:", i + 1); //length
                        barSpecs[i][3] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar change in time {0}:", i + 1); // Delta t
                        barSpecs[i][4] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar cold temp {0}:", i + 1); //T2
                        barSpecs[i][5] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter bar hot temp {0}:", i + 1);  //T1
                        barSpecs[i][6] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        barSpecs[i][7] = -((barSpecs[i][1] * barSpecs[i][2]) / barSpecs[i][3]) * (barSpecs[i][5] - barSpecs[i][6]) * barSpecs[i][4];
                        barSpecs[i][8] = barSpecs[i][7] / barSpecs[i][4];
                        Console.Clear();
                    }

                    //    //structured output 
                    Console.WriteLine("Material        Lamda           T2      T1     Delta T    Length     Area      Delta Q/Delta t  ");
                    Console.WriteLine("          (cal/sec)/(C cm)     (C)     (C)     (Sec)      (cm)     (sq cm)     (cal/sec) ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberofUserInputs; i++)
                        Console.WriteLine("               {1:F2}          {2:F2}   {3:F2}     {4:F2}     {5:F2}       {6:F2}       {7:F2}", "ultimate", barSpecs[i][1], barSpecs[i][5], barSpecs[i][6], barSpecs[i][4], barSpecs[i][3], barSpecs[i][2], barSpecs[i][8]);
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers only");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Would like to continue? (Y = yes, N = no)");
            } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

I need the barSpecp[i][1] to be able to change with the different input from the question "Enter Material Type of bar {0}:"
I thought adding an if else statement would work but doesnt to do it correctly.

Comment: `if(int.TryParse(intputstring, outS))` <-- `int.TryParse` will either succeed or fail on the first try, there's no sense in trying again 3 more times with the same input

Comment: Can you work through an example numerically stating given a specific set of inputs, what the expected outputs should be?

Comment: Is this code really the most **minimal** way to reproduce the problem you are facing?

Comment: You're just missing a Console.Readline after `Console.WriteLine("Enter Material` ...  This is likely a facepalm error.  And either careless debugging or lack of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You're having trouble where your program **asks the material type of the bar**. It appears that what you're trying to do here is better evaluated using a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) statement. And your intention and code would be more clear if you replaced these comments:

```
//silver = 1
//Aluminum = 0.5f
//Fiberglass = 0.045f
//Glass = 0.002f
```

with a meaningful `enum` in code.

```
enum Material
{
    [Description("1.00")]
    Silver = 1,

    [Description("0.50")]
    Aluminum,

    [Description("0.045")]
    Fiberglass,

    [Description("0.002")]
    Glass,
}
```

---

Use `TryParse` to validate the user's input:

```
string UserInputPrompt = "How many bars to consider? ";
Console.Write(UserInputPrompt);

int NumberofUserInputs;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out NumberofUserInputs))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid integer required");
}
```

---

The enumeration can be used to inform the user about which key to hit for which material:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Enter Material Type of bar {i + 1}");
foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Material)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{(int)value}: {value}");
}
```

[image: menu driven app]

In this case, try a `ReadKey` to get the single character and validate it.

```
Material material;
while (true)
{
    var intVal = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).Key - ConsoleKey.D0;
    if(1 <= intVal && intVal <=4)
    {
        material = (Material)intVal;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber between 1 and 4 required");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
barSpecs[i][1] = float.Parse(((DescriptionAttribute)
    typeof(Material).GetField(material.ToString())
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
    .First())
    .Description);
Console.WriteLine($"\nValue={barSpecs[i][1]}");
```